# How to display hex numbers greater than 15 (0Fh) without using printf?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So, here's an annoying question:
[The last line contains the question, the remaining stuff is a background to better understand the requirement.]

In assembly, we could easily use the printf function to display stuff.. It automatically converts binary data into characters correctly.

Now, in my assignments I am required to work with hex numbers and display the sum of 10 such numbers accurately.
I have already accomplished categorizing and converting the ascii to hex numbers (stored in a nibble/4-bit) using the code:

Disclaimer:

1) The esi register contains the memory location at which the number must be saved.

2) The temp is a buffer of 5 bytes which is supposed to take maximum 4 character input without trouble.

```
in:             ; loop to take one multidigit input

mov ebx, 1      ;set error flag
scan temp, 5    ;take input
mov ecx, [temp]
mov edi, 4      ;assumes 4 digit input, works for 0 to 4 digit input

test:           ;a validation check for input!!
cmp cl, 0Dh     ;if current byte contains '\r'
je hop          ;skip it

test0:
cmp cl, 030H    ;cl >= '0'
jge test9       ;if yes, check if cl is digit
xor ebx, ebx    ;otherwise, set error signal
jmp cont

test9:
cmp cl, 039h    ;cl <= '9'
jle cont        ;if yes, cl is a digit, case closed
jmp test10c     ;otherwise, check if cl has hex character

test10c:        ;for caps 'A'
cmp cl, 041h    ;cl >= 10 (in caps char hex)
jge test15c     ;if yes, check if cl is a caps hex character
xor ebx, ebx    ;otherwise, set error signal
jmp cont

test15c:
cmp cl, 046h    ;cl <= 15 (in hex)
jle conv        ;if yes, cl is a caps hex character, case closed
jmp test10s     ;otherwise check if cl has small hex character

test10s:
cmp cl, 061h    ;cl >= 10 (in small char hex)
jge test15s     ;if yes, check if cl is a small hex character
xor ebx, ebx    ;otherwise, set error signal
jmp cont

test15s:
cmp cl, 066h    ;cl <= 15 (in small char hex)
jle cont        ;if yes, cl is a small hex character, case closed
xor ebx, ebx    ;otherwise, set error signal

cont:
cmp ebx, 1      ;check for error
jne err         ;if error, jump to err (abort loop)
jmp hop         ;otherwise continue to next ascii character entered

hop:
rol ecx, 8      ;roll next character into cl
dec edi         ;there are only 4 roll-in operations until you repeat the number
jnz test        ;loop back to testing

end:
mov dword[temp], ecx    ;store number between call
call conv               ;convert number
mov ecx, [temp]         ;take converted number
mov dword[esi], ecx     ;store it in array
mov dword[temp], 0      ;store success signal
jmp quit

err:
mov dword[temp], 0FFh   ;store error signal

quit:                   ;return to caller
ret

conv:           ; loop to convert one multidigit input to specific format 
mov ecx, dword[temp]    ;take number
mov edi, 4              ;set number of rotations

fix:
cmp cl, 0Dh     ;check with '\r'
mov cl, 0       ;'\r' will be stored as 0, the numbers 0-15 will be stored as 1-16
jmp skip
cmp cl, 046h    ;check with 'F'
jle digitize    ;if less, convert caps character to digit
sub cl, 020h    ;if more, convert small character to caps
digitize:
cmp cl, 039h    ;check with '9'
jle norm        ;if less, convert ascii digit to normal digit
sub cl, 07h     ;if more, convert character to ascii digit
norm:
sub cl, 030h    ;convert ascii digit to hex digit
add cl, 01h     ;encode 0-15 as 1-16 to accomodate '\r'

skip:
rol ecx, 8      ;roll next character into cl
dec edi         ;there are only 4 roll-in operations until you repeat the number
jnz fix

ret
```

Here is have encoded the digits in a specific fashion. You may suggest otherwise to increase the simplicity of the addition algorithm.

Finally, quoting the question:

"How do you use the sys_write(function no. 4) to write out the sum of these encoded numbers correctly into stdout(file descriptor 1)?"

Comment: If I wish to convert 100d to hex, I would use a calculator... :boom-tish: Failing that, I'd divide 100 by 16. This would give me 6.25 - or to put it another way, 6 remainder 4. I'd store the remainder in the last available location in your array and then check if the result was larger than 15. If so, repeat. If not, put the 6 into the 2nd last pos of your array. You know, standard base-conversion stuff. The important things to keep track of are **(a)** the number of digits you've output (so you know where to start displaying the contents of the array from) **(b)** digits larger than 9 are A-F

Comment: If you're ok with leading zeroes, start with the most significant nibble of the sum, isolate those 4 bits and convert to a hex character (`'0'..'F'`), print it or add it to a buffer, then proceed with the next nibble. Stop when you've processed all 8 nibbles (or 4, or 2, or whatever). If you don't want any leading zeroes you'll have to start by scanning for the most significant non-zero nibble.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.. 
You see, the numbers will be stored as a maximum of 4 digit hex. So maximum sum will be 0F0F0F0F + 0F0F0F0F = F0F0F0F0
a three digit displayable number for a single byte of result. This situation will therefore create a logical error.
The program is actually designed to run the sum of (say N) numbers whose total sum will be less than 0F0F0F0F or less than 252645135 in decimal @enhzflep

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.. Could you help me out by actually writing down that algorithm? I didn't quite understand how you'd accomplish that.. @Michael

Comment: It's just a loop where you ROL 4 bits per iteration and then isolate the 4 bits you want to process using a bitwise AND.

Comment: @Adil - that's okay. Your comment seems rather odd - 4 digit hex would typically be understood to mean a number whose range is [0000 - FFFF]. Could you explain the math you're using in your last comment? If I take 0x0F0F0F0F (252,645,135) and add it to 0x0F0F0F0F I get 0x1E1E1E1E (505,290,270). It seems very strange that you'd leave the high nibble as 0 in all of your hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: oh yeah, right.. I got confused with binary right there.. :P
Anyway, the current encoding [0 -> \r, (1-10)->(0,9), (11,16)->(A,F)] requires to reserve a byte for each digit. Packing the numbers and unpacking them would require an unnecessary paradigm.
If some other encoding help to fix the probable error, it'd be very helpful! @enhzflep

Comment: I think you're complicating it unnecessarily. If you add together 10, 16-bit numbers, the largest sum can be 0x9FFF6 (This is 10 * 0xFFFF). This perfectly fits in with your buffer array of 5 characters. So, simply add the 10 numbers together, ensuring that you use a 32 bit register for the accumulated total. Once done, simply convert the register's lowest 20 bits to ascii. After the 4-bit nibble for each character is isolated, you can add '0' to it if it's 9 or under, otherwise you can add 'A' to it. Once isolated and translated to ascii print it. Repeat x4, This will print 2,550 as 009F6. :)

Comment: See, for any numerical character to be displayed, it must be converted to ascii byte. Now on removing the ascii addendum, only 1 nibble of number is produced. Addition of two nibbles may lead to a byte result. I should be able to carry that upper nibble to next byte for proper addition. I'm unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you appear to be coding under linux, I've chosen to offer a routine for hex formatted 32 bit number printing that I've just knocked together in a dos-box environment. You'll need to use a different mechanism than `int 0x10, func E` for printing out each character of the output. You'll also need to alter the stack-frame stuff to allow for the fact that vars pushed onto the stack are 4 bytes by default rather than 2. I.e bp+4 (bp+2*2) becomes bp+8 (bp+2*4) and ret 4 (ret 2*2) becomes ret 8 (ret 2*4)

You may also elect to forget about manually worrying about addition overflow and the carry flag - the processor doesn't need its hand held for something so trivial.

```
xor ebx, ebx  ; total = 0
mov eax, 300
add ebx, eax  ; total = total + 300
mov eax, 200
add ebx, eax  ; total = total + 200
; etc, etc
```

The flow-chart for such a printing function is surprisingly short. I suggest you flow-chart the code yourself (by hand) to help clarify the algorithm in your mind.

First, the code:

```
[section .text]
[bits 16]

EntryPoint:
    push    long 0xDEADBEEF
    call    printHexLong

    ; print CRLF
    mov     ah, 0xe
    mov     al, 10
    int     0x10
    mov     al, 13
    int     0x10

    push    long 3735928559
    call    printHexLong

    ret

;void printHexLong(ulong32 num) 
printHexLong
    push    bp
    mov     bp, sp

    mov     ebx, [bp+4]         ; get the input var
    mov     cx, 8               ; number of nibbles to do
.printLoop:
    rol     ebx, 4              ; 0x11223344 becomes 0x12233441
    mov     al, bl              ; al = 0x41
    and     al, 0xF             ; al = 0x01

    cmp     al, 10              ; will this nibble be 0..9 or will it be A..F ?
    jb      .oneToNine
    sub     al, 10              ; nibble is > 9, so it's A..F  - subtract 10 so it's 0..9, 
    add     al, 'A'             ; then add ascii value of 'A'
    jmp     .outputNibble

.oneToNine:
    add     al, '0'             ; nibble is < 10, so it's a digit 0..9

.outputNibble:
    mov     ah, 0xe             ; video bios int - output a single character in teletype mode
    int     0x10                ; output the nibble

    dec     cx                  ; decrement nibble counter
    jnz     .printLoop          ; any left? If so, go again.

    pop     bp                  ; restore original value of bp
    ret     4                   ;remove the input var from the stack
```

And now the output:

```
DEADBEEF
DEADBEEF
```